# Loading assembly compiled at runtime into different AppDomain fails

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I try to load a DLL which was compiled at runtime into a different AppDomain. This does not work while doing the same for system.dll works. This is my test code:

```
string sourceCode = "using System;\r\n" +
                     "[Serializable]\r\n" +
                     "public class Program1{\r\n" +
                     "   public static void Main1(){\r\n" +
                     "     int i = 100;\r\n" +
                     "     i++;" + 
                     "   }\r\n" +
                     "}";

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
Assembly[] assembliesOfCurrentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();//this.CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

for (int runAssembliesInCurrDomain = 0; runAssembliesInCurrDomain < assembliesOfCurrentDomain.Length; runAssembliesInCurrDomain++)
{
    try
    {
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assembliesOfCurrentDomain[runAssembliesInCurrDomain].Location);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

// True - memory generation, false - external file generation
parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = "D:\\temp\\123.dll";
parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

// True - exe file generation, false - dll file generation
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceCode);

Assembly own = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\temp\\123.dll");
Assembly system = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System");

AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
    PrivateBinPath = @"D:\\temp"
};

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("hello", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, appDomainSetup);
domain.Load(system.GetName());               // works
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(own.GetName()); // works
domain.Load(own.GetName());                  // works not
```

I get a FileNotFoundException with the following "FusionLog"

```
=== Zustandsinformationen vor Bindung ===
LOG: Benutzer = LIGHTTRANS2\schoening
LOG: DisplayName = 123, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/schoening/Projekte_VL/Testprojekte/Compileing/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/
LOG: Ursprünglicher PrivatePath = NULL
Aufruf von Assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: Diese Bindung startet im default-Load-Kontext.
LOG: Die Anwendungskonfigurationsdatei wird verwendet: D:\schoening\Projekte_VL\Testprojekte\Compileing\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\x64\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Die Computerkonfigurationsdatei von C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config wird verwendet.
LOG: Die Richtlinie wird derzeit nicht auf den Verweis angewendet (private, benutzerdefinierte, teilweise oder pfadbasierte Assemblybindung)
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///D:/schoening/Projekte_VL/Testprojekte/Compileing/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/123.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///D:/schoening/Projekte_VL/Testprojekte/Compileing/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/123/123.DLL.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///D:/schoening/Projekte_VL/Testprojekte/Compileing/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/123.EXE.
LOG: Download von neuem URL file:///D:/schoening/Projekte_VL/Testprojekte/Compileing/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/x64/Debug/123/123.EXE.
```

Sorry that it is German, tomorrow I will try to post an English version.
Any ideas what's the difference between the two assemblies?

The compiling of the DLL works. I have the same problem if I comment out everything before the `Assembly own = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\temp\\123.dll")` line and use the DLL compiled in the previous run.

**Edit:**
Following a suggestion, I tried the following which does not work either.

```
 Assembly own = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\temp\\123.dll");

 AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup() {
     PrivateBinPath = @"D:\\temp"
 };

 //FileStream fs = own.GetFiles(true)[0]; // does not work either
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\temp\\123.dll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
 byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[fs.Length];
 fs.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)fs.Length);

 AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("hello", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, appDomainSetup);
 domain.Load(rawAssembly);
```

Comment: Why are you loading the assembly into the application domain? What are you trying to do here? Why don't you just load the assembly from the *inside* of the application domain, when it's actually needed?

Comment: We want to achieve that the user can control our application via own code. In this code he shall be able to use external DLLs. And it shall be possible that these DLLs are changed while our application is running and the changes are applied without restarting our application.

Comment: Wait a minute, it fails on the *first* `Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\temp\\123.dll")` already? Also, note that you're setting the private bin path incorrectly (`@"D:\\temp"` gives `D:\\temp`, not `D:\temp`). What exception do you get with the new approach?

Comment: @Luaan : Of course you are right with the `D:\temp` :-). But this changes nothing. 
No, my code either fails in the line `domain.Load(own.GetName());` (original approach) or the line `domain.Load(rawAssembly);` (byte array approach). Each time with the same exception and the same fusion log.

Comment: I have just tried to load the system.dll of the .Net framework with the "byte array approach", i.e. loading it from file and converting it to a byte array. This works. (With the original approach it works not). So the problem seems to be not the loading in the different AppDomain but the compiling. I now have to find the compile settings which make my 123.dll behave like the system.dll.

Comment: That's weird... could it be that he assembly is already loaded in the new appdomain (or another assembly with the same name)?

Comment: I have just compared the properties of the resulting assembly if I load system.dll and 123.dll. The significant differences are `GlobalAssemblyCache` is true for System.dll but false for 123.dll. `SecurityRuleSet` is Level1 for System.dll but Level2 for 123.dll. MSDN states "The .NET Framework version 4 always enforces level 2 transparency for the dynamic assemblies it generates."

Comment: @Luaan As I create the new AppDomain "from scratch", no DLL should be loaded in there?

Comment: @TSchoening Have you managed to solve your problem? I'm stuck on similar issue.

Comment: @JustasG Unfortunately not. We postponed solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly name doesn't contain a full path to the assembly - the CLR doesn't have any way of finding your "temp" assembly. If you want to load a specific assembly *file* into an `AppDomain`, you'll have to use the `byte[]` overload.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and unfortunately it doesn't work. See my modified question.